# How to know which database that Spring Framework MongoDB Repository is store the data to?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have an issue, where I store data into a MongoDB Database by using the Spring Framework MongoDB Repository. The `save()` is working without exception, and I can even retrieve the data when I run the same program.

However, I cannot find the data in the Database, I also could not retrieve the data using another program despite using the same Database settings.

Here is my app.settings:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb://root:${spring.data.mongodb.password}@localhost:17951/user?authSource=admin&maxIdleTimeMS=5000
```

The password will be retrieved from AWS Secret Manager, here are the source code for it:

```
@Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationPreparedEvent event) {
        // Get username and password from AWS Secret Manager
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = event.getApplicationContext().getEnvironment();
        String[] profile= environment.getActiveProfiles();
        String secretName = null;
        if(profile.length>0) {
            if (profile[0].equalsIgnoreCase("dev")) {
                secretName = "dev-secrets";
            } else if (profile[0].equalsIgnoreCase("qa")) {
                secretName = "qa-secrets";
            } else {
                secretName = profile[0] + "-secrets";
            }
        }else{
            secretName = "dev-secrets";
        }
        String secretJson = getSecret(secretName);
        String dbPasswordMongo = getString(secretJson, "user-db");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(SPRING_DATASOURCE_MONGODB_PASSWORD, dbPasswordMongo);
        environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new PropertiesPropertySource("aws.secret.manager", props));
    }
```

This part is working as I can see it is retrieving the correct password from Secret Manager.

Then, I proceed my program to store data into the DB. Here are my repository:

```
//This is Repository Class
@CrossOrigin
@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "item", path = "item")
public interface ItemRepository extends MongoRepository<Item, String> {
}
```

```
//This is Service Layer Class
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Item saveItem(Item item) {
        try{
            return itemRepo.save(item);
        } catch (Exception ex){
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The `save()` went well with no exception. Later in the exact same program have another `find()` command which successfully retrieved the item that just saved.

However, when I run the Database Command in Robo3T, the data did not show in the specified `item` database as I expected: `db.getCollection('item').find({})` returns `Fetched 0 record(s) in 94ms`.

And if I run another program (which is an API) that tries to retrieve from `item` database, there is nothing to retrieve.

I suspect it is store into wrong database or wrong connection string lead to different database, however I cannot seems to get which database it is store into.

How can I know which database the program is really connected and store into?

Thank you.

Comment: You are catching error in save repository and return null. Are you sure it does not throw exception?

Comment: Hi @Gurkanİlleez, I run the program locally in debug mode and have a break point over there, so should it throw any exception I will get it.

Comment: When you add transactional you can not catch it but at least you tried normal flow and you didnt see exception. Also why do you need service layer?

Comment: Spring data rest does not trigger service layer repository layer opens endpoints for you

Comment: You can handle bussiness logic withevent  handlers

Answer (score 0):

As per syntax of the mongoDB uri to mention in spring boot is as below-

mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[defaultauthdb][?options]]
Source - [source url](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/)

So in your case default database is "user"

Comment: Yes, however it should be inside collection named `item` right? I do not see the data being inside of collection `item`.